# Code Coverage 95% in sandbox and 47% in production for a class

Tags: apex, deployment, code-coverage, code

I am at a loss right now why my code coverage is off for a particular class. I have @isTest(seeAllData = false) in my test class and I am creating my own data.  I have also cloned a new sandbox from production to make sure the environments were the same.  Also, anyone know if there is anyway to see what parts of my code were not covered during deployment instead of just a message saying it did not hit code coverage. Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks strange to me. I would like to suggest you to create a case at [partner community](https://partners.salesforce.com/partnerSupport) and provide access to investigate it, and update the result back here as answer for us to know as well. Cheers!

Comment: When you click that dropdown box, how many unique test classes (which is different from the number of test methods that you'll see) show up as contributing towards the coverage for this class?  Are all of those test classes either in your production environment or being included in your deployment?

Comment: Hello Derek.  These test classes are in my change set.  All my test classes pass 100% in this change set except for this particular one. In my drop down box I have All Tests 95% TestProfitLostUtil.test 95%